# Generation of random 2D integration path

Tags: matlab, random, path, numerical-integration

I'm trying to compute a direct spatial integration of a scalar field. For technical reasons, I want a single-point boundary condition to start the integration and I want a random integration path in order to avoid directivity effects in error accumulation. But here I have a problem trying to generate efficiently a random 2D integration path. Typically, what should be done is :

1. Select one random grid index where boundary condition is applied and where the integration starts.
2. Select randomly one adjacent grid index to integrate.
3. Select randomly one grid index already integrated AND which has adjacent grid index not integrated.
   Then repeat 2. and 3. until the whole grid is integrated.

I'm having an issue trying to find an efficient solution to generated such a path, without having to each time look at all the adjacent grid index of all the elements to check the condition in 2.

Does anyone have a couple of leads to find a solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you integrating at *points*? Integration requires a range... Are you just looking for the index selection algorithm described in steps 1-3?

Comment: Integration is not a problem, just looking for the path generation. By integration I mean calculating the field from the known gradient on all the grid and the field itself at an adjacent point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it might be related to Poisson Disk sampling, see [here](https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/) or details. Basically, it is kind of linear O(N) growth algorithm proposed by R.Bridson http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf

Comment: Indeed, it looks like something I could use. I'll give it a try. Thanks.